# SQL Index - Recreate after DELETE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a temp table `#Data`, that I populate inside a stored procedure.

It contains like 15M rows.

Then I create a clustered index, say `IX_Data`, for a couple of column of the temp table `#Data`.

Then I delete from `#Data` which deletes like 1M rows (keeping the total rows 14M now).

My question: at this point, should I drop `IX_Data` and recreate it?

`#Data` is being referred further in the rest of the stored procedure just at one place.

Comment: What is the motivation for the question? Why do you ask?

Comment: Since you mention *clustered index*, I assumed this is for `sql-server` - correct?? **SQL** is just the query language - not the database product - so that really isn't enough to be able to help you. Please always tell us what **concrete database** (`sql-server`, `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql` etc.) and what version/edition you're using!

Comment: Sorry folks, forgot to mention. I use SQL Server 2014

Comment: I am optimizing some 4 years old code, and I saw this and found a little awkward. That motivates me to ask.

Comment: @GreenBinary: you don't mix maintenance with business logic. That's it.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to get some good opinion so that I can optimize my proc. That's it. There is no business logic I'm talking about here. Please let me know if this is not a place to ask this kind of questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should not. Indexes are maintained by dbms automatically and always kept in sync.

That's why it's not recommended to create more indexes than you need since it's a performance penalty for every DML query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which database you are on (maybe it's Oracle?), but your question seems about **fragmentation**, since data integrity should be mantained in every database even if you delete a million of rows (so there's no need to drop and recreate an index *for data integrity*).

So, how do you know if your index is fragmented (so you need to recreate, or better, *rebuild* it)? Every database has his method. Oracle has internal tables from which you can determine if an object is fragmented.

But it depends on your type of database.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2014. Looks like I can remove drop and create index statement from my proc.